# Getting Client ip address from request in WebSphere

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, proxy, websphere, ip-address

I have a scenario where i need to retrieve the client's ipaddress from the request

The code that I am using to get the client's ipaddress is:

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if (ipAddress == null) {
                    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
                }
```

As per my understanding, `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` will return the client's ipaddress if there is a proxy in between. If there is no proxy in between client and app server, `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` will return null but `request.getRemoteAddr()` can return the ipaddress in that case.

For my local development, I do not have any proxy or loadbalancer in between. So, in the above code, `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` will return me null and then I can get the ipaddress from `request.getRemoteAddr();`which seems to be working alright.

For my qa and prod environments, we have an F5 LOAD BALANCER which routes the request to IHS Webserver which would then route the request to Websphere appserver on which this code would be deployed.

so, in this distributed environment, iam guessing `request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")` should return me the client's ipaddress correctly. I sis not have a chance to test this in a distributed environment yet.

Is my thinking correct or are there any issues with this approach ?

Advance thanks.

Is my thinking right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is mostly correct, but these things are worth noting:

1. The header is actually X-Forwarded-For (note the case).
2. [You can have more than one such header](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/4000/800/sol4816.html).
3. [The header itself can contain more than one IP address.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: Case 2 is uncommon unless you have multiple F5's involved, but if so you'll want to grab the first header. For case 3, you'll want to split the header string up and use the first entry as your client IP. Subsequent entries are supposed to be other proxies in the chain between the client and your server.

Comment: cool...thanks... Now to enable X-Forwarded-For functionality, should the F5 be modified in some way or should be able to forward client ip address as it is by default

Comment: Yeah, you have to tell F5 to add that header. The link in my case 2 shows you the two options for doing that.